# 7z multifile recover from partial file loss

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

I have one 7z file that has been split into separate parts (to email them). Some parts (2/60) are missing (in the middle of the series).

So, I have `file.7z.001` until `file.7z.039` and `file.7z.041` until `file.7z.060`.

Unsurprisingly I cannot open the 7zip file anymore. I tried concatenating the files I have, but that did not help.

I tried various switches of the `7za` command, but as there is not sufficient documentation on what they mean, I'm unsure if anything of that was useful.

I had a second file with the same problem and after recovering the missing parts the file opened just fine. So I know that the files are openable.

I'm on a Linux but I'm willing to use Tools on other systems as well if they help my problem.

Output of `7za x file.7z.001`:

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 15.14 : Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Igor Pavlov : 2015-12-31
p7zip Version 15.14.1 (locale=de_DE.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz (506E3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 10485760 bytes (10 MiB)

Extracting archive: file.7z.001
ERROR: file.7z.001
file.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Is not archive

Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
```

Comment: What does a regular attempt to extract using `7z x file.7z.001` print? And also, _how_ was the archive split – using native 7zip functionality, or external tools?

Comment: @grawity I'll add the output this evening when I'm back home. I don't know what packed the original files (and don't know how to find out). I assume it had been made by the windows 7zip tool.

Comment: @grawity Maybe interesting is that I have another file where I have all the parts. That file can be unpacked easily by opening the 001 file via my graphical tool (I'll look up the name).

Comment: @grawity I added the output as by your request.